# Can't add more elements to the ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to add more elements to the ArrayList, but I'm receiving these errors:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
    at Gestor.adicionarProduto(Gestor.java:32)
```

The first thing that I'm doing is checking if the Arraylist is emtpy to add the first element. And I'm checking if the ArrayList is not empty to compare and add more elements.

```
   if(!arProduct.isEmpty()){
        for(Produto produto : arProduct){
            String receivePosicao = letraPrateleira.toLowerCase() + nrPosicao;
            String searchPosicao = produto.getLetraPrateleira() + produto.getNrPosicao();

            if(receivePosicao.equals(searchPosicao)){
                System.out.println("Esta posição encontra-se ocupada por outro produto.");
            }else{
                arProduct.add(new Produto(nomeProduto, precoProduto, mensagemAdicional, letraPrateleira, nrPosicao)); 
            }

        }

    }

    if(arProduct.isEmpty(){
        arProduto.add(new Produto("a", 2, "a", "a", 1)); 
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Do not modify the list while iterating over it.

Comment: So, I shouldn't use the second if statement right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding elements while iterating over the list!

Add your elements in a temporary list and add them after iterating:

```
List<Produto> toAdd = new ArrayList<>();
for(Produto produto : arProduct) {
   // ...
   toAdd.add(new Produto(nomeProduto, precoProduto, mensagemAdicional, letraPrateleira, nrPosicao));
}
produto.addAll(toAdd);
```

Comment: Oh, I will never do this mistake again, thank you, the code is working now.

Comment: You can add to an `ArrayList` while iterating over it if you iterate using `ListIterator`. The `for` syntax will just get an `Iterator` however, which does not allow you to add while iterating.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify a list while iterating over it.
Make your method return a boolean if the list needs to be modified, and then modify the list outside.

The else statement and the second if would return true, and that should cause the list to be modified.

Comment: You can modify while iterating:         ListIterator<String> listIterator = arrayList.listIterator();
        while (listIterator.hasNext()) {
            listIterator.next();
            if (/*some condition*/) {
                listIterator.add("some string");
            }
        }

Comment: Just referring to the List interface here. But I agree, a listiterator is better